# Saving big amount of data (words): Serialization or DB

Tags: java, database, performance, serialization, data-structures

I need to save permanently a big vocabulary and associate to each word some information (and use it to search words efficiently).
Is it better to store it in a DB (in a simply table and let the DBMS make the work of structuring data based on the key) or is it better to create a 
trie data structure and then serialize it to a file and deserialize once the program is started, or maybe instead of serialization use a XML file?

**Edit**: the vocabulary would be in the order of 5 thousend to 10 thousend words in size, and for each word the metadata are structured in array of 10 Integer. The access to the word is very frequent (this is why I thought to trie data structure that have a search time ~O(1) instead of DB that use B-tree or something like that  where the search is ~O(logn)).

p.s. using java.
Thanks!

Comment: most likely you would want to use JPA and a DB behind it, but this depends on a lot of factors (how many words, how much meta-data, how much available ram, with which likelihood and frequency are words accessed, what are the performance requirements, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using DB is better.

many companies are merged to DB, like the erp divalto was using serializations and now merged to DB to get performance

you have many choices between DBMS, if you want to see all data in one file the simple way is to use `SQLITE`. his advantage it not need any server DBMS running.